# How do I copy the location of a track to the "Comments" section in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, applescript

I dont understand why this is not working. If anybody knows how to resolve this issue:

> ```
> tell application "iTunes"
>   copy location of track 1 of playlist "Test" to Comments
> end tell
> ```

Applescript does now show an error but when I see in iTunes, the "Comments" field is still empty.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because you copy the location to the `Comments` variable.

Here's how to put the location in the `comment` tag.

> ```
> tell application "iTunes"
>   tell track 1 of playlist "Test" to set comment to (its location as text)
>   -- or set comment  of track 1 of playlist "Test" to (get location of track 1 of playlist "Test") as text
> end tell
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set theLocation to location of track 1 of playlist "Test"
    set the comment of track 1 of playlist "Test" to POSIX path of theLocation as string
end tell
```

The `as string` is the key here, otherwise the types are incompatible.

If you want it as a one liner, you can do:

```
tell application "iTunes" to copy the POSIX path of (location of track 1 of playlist "Test" as string) to comment of track 1 of playlist "Test"
```

If you want the old Mac style paths with colons (`Macintosh HD:Users:rob:Music`) instead of Unix style (`/Users/rob/Music`), you can remove the `POSIX path of` parts of either of those.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to remove root directories from the path, run on multiple files, and skip if there is already anything in the field, (and copy to description not comments), so I did:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    if selection is not {} then -- there are tracks selected
        -- store current sort so we can fix during run
        set oldfi to fixed indexing
        set fixed indexing to true
        set mySelection to selection
        repeat with aTrack in mySelection
            -- if description empty
            set old_desc to ((get description of aTrack) as text)
            if old_desc is "" then
                -- get path of file
                set loc to POSIX path of ((get location of aTrack) as text)
                -- replace /Users/techtitch/Music/ with ~Music/
                set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "/Users/username/Music/"
                set the item_list to every text item of loc
                set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "~Music/"
                set loc to the item_list as string
                -- store path in description property of file
                set description of aTrack to loc
            end if
        end repeat
        -- restore prior sort
        set fixed indexing to oldfi
    end if
end tell
```

Then just save as `/Users/username/Library/iTunes/Scripts/Copy selected files path to description.scpt` (create directories if they're not already there).

Credit to dougscripts.com for the primer.